# webmail.example.com throws 404 for HTTPS only on hosted server

Tags: https, custom-error-pages

I have a several web sites running on a shared hosted server.
Every site except one I can enter in my browser **https**://webmail.example.com or **http**://webmail.example.com and they both work and resolve to the secure or insecure pages accordingly.

On the one site the page resolves correctly for regular http but I get a "404 Not found" error when I try https for the webmail subdomain of that site. https://myexample.com does work for all pages on that site (without the webmail subdomain).

All of the DNS settings are the same for all of the sites. There is a CNAME record webmail.example.com --> examplecom. None of the sites have a "proper" subdomain setup where the subdoman points to a directory, just the DNS setting. The SSL Status reports that the SSL cert for the webmail subdomain is valid.
Im not sure what else to check or how webmail ultimately get pointed  to the webmail page.

Comment: Need more details. Logs or configuration files

Comment: which logs or configs? it is on a hosted server so I only have access to some.

Comment: Can you show us some screenshot of HTTPS configuration of the site?. Check any possible log or more information. Because "404 Not found"  is just  a common error.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to check/show. In my original question I included what I thought was helpful. I'm not sure where else to look.